# Highcharts treemap with drillnodes and color axis : do not display sub level colors in the main level

Tags: highcharts, treemap

I'm working on Treemap combined with Heatmap (to get the colorAxis feature) and multi-levels (to drill in the data).
It works fine, can see here the sample result  http://jsfiddle.net/vegaelce/q5n4bur3.

```
colorAxis: {
    minColor: "#ffffff",
    maxColor: "#0000ff"
},  
series: [{
type: "treemap",
layoutAlgorithm: 'sliceAndDice',
allowDrillToNode: true,
alternateStartingDirection: true,
levelIsConstant: false,
dataLabels: {
  enabled: false
},
levels: [{
  level: 1,      
  dataLabels: {
    enabled: true,        
  },
  borderWidth: 3
},{
  level: 2,      
  borderWidth: 2
},{
  level: 3,      
  borderWidth: 1
}],
data: [
{ name:'Accessories',
id:'Accessories',
value: 6297610.2,
colorValue: 6297610.2,
}, 
{ name:'Dresses',
value: 1587737.4,
colorValue: 1587737.4,
}, 
{ name:'City Trousers',
value: 171824.3,
colorValue: 171824.3,
}, 
{ name:'City Skirts',
value: 171570.4,
colorValue: 171570.4,
}, 

{
name: '2014', id: 'Accessories_2014', value: 3499307.1, parent: 'Accessories',colorValue: 3499307
},{
name: '2015',value: 1926600.4, parent: 'Accessories',colorValue: 1926600
},{
name: '2016',value: 871702.7, parent: 'Accessories',colorValue: 871702
},

{
name: 'Q1', id: 'Accessories_2014_Q1', value: 6297610.1, parent: 'Accessories_2014',colorValue: 6297610
},
{
name: 'Q2', id: 'Accessories_2014_Q2', value: 171824.1, parent: 'Accessories_2014',colorValue: 171824
},
{
name: 'Q3', id: 'Accessories_2014_Q3', value: 109307.1, parent: 'Accessories_2014',colorValue: 109307
}
]
}]
```

What I need, to clarify the reading of this kind of chart, is to display on a given level, only one color  for each group-node (not the colors of the children values).
For example, in my dataset, I'd like on the first level, see one color for the "Accessories" group (the dark blue we can see when hover the group with the mouse).
When we click on "Accessories", then we can see only one color for "2014"...

Is it possible and if yes, how can I do that ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I am afraid that the jsFiddle link which you shared doesn't work. Could you attach a working one?

Comment: Hi, the link has been fixed. You can try again (http://jsfiddle.net/vegaelce/q5n4bur3/)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/841Lxsuj/ I used the render callback to update the `colorAxis` colors after the `drilldown` event has been triggered.

```
events: {
  render() {
    let chart = this;

    if (chartForRender) {
      chartForRender = false;
      if (chart.series[0].drillUpButton) {
        chart.update({
          colorAxis: {
            minColor: "red",
            maxColor: "orange"
          }
        })
      } else {
        chart.update({
          colorAxis: {
            minColor: "#ffffff",
            maxColor: "#0000ff"
          }
        })
      }
    }
    chartForRender = true;
  }
}
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.render

API: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#update